# Inkscape: wrap text and objects on a label around a bottle

Tags: inkscape

[image]How can I progressively decrease the width of a *group of objects* or *texts* in inkscape 1.2? (From top to bottom in image below).
I tried various path effects and build-in extensions, but none of them could gradually decrease the both sides (or one side).
I would use this to wrap text and objects on a label around a bottle with the viewpoint directly in the middle. So the height remains the same but left and right should be more condensed than the middle.

Comment: Please read: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You can use the *Lattice Live Path Effect* to achieve this in a non destructive manner.

Make sure all your objects composing your label are actual paths. If there are texts convert them to paths, if there are clone instances unlink them.

Join all your label objects into a group. Select the group and go to *Path > Path Effects*. Select lattice and add it to the group.

[image]

From the *Live path Effect* palette dialog turn on the options *Mirror movements horizontal*, *Mirror movements vertical*, and *Use only perimeter*.

[image]

With the label group object selected (not any of its individual contents) choose the *Node* tool from the toolbar and drag one of the middle top or bottom handles to the side, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to constraint to orthogonal movement.

[image]

Comment: This is very nice and I've learnt a new tool from it, but if I could make a suggestion: Yes, it should have been obvious to me in hindsight, but before dragging the handles you need to activate the node tool - perhaps this is worth mentioning

Comment: Indeed, edited for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at the exponential_distort extension:
https://gitea.fablabchemnitz.de/FabLab_Chemnitz/mightyscape-1.1-deprecated/src/branch/master/extensions/fablabchemnitz/exponential_distort